# Suggestion on Payment gateway

Tags: payment-gateway

I am developing a MVC web application and one of its feature is to implement credit card transaction and upon goggling I found many references to payment gateways (ZipZap,Paytoo etc..) as I haven't worked earlier on Payment gateway 
and wanted to know which one should be picked as to startup and provide a trial for sandbox testing in dev environment.

Any suggestion or help on this would be of great help.

Comment: Harry is my answer useful for you?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tp start with it's useful as I was engage with other priority tasks did not get enough time to implement the same..Also, I was looking for a sceneiro where in the application could configure multiple gateways and on selection can use one particular.

Comment: Actually paypal, stripe or payu has payment gateways at their structure, when you integrate this system you automatically have multiple gateways but i understand from your requirement you want to manage payment gateways as a custom logic, good luck.

Comment: your response appreciated and want to know if  Authorize.net does support  multiple gateways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `Stripe` and `Paypal` Sandbox, and also more information about payment gateways and their comparations check my answer at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28583292/payment-gateway-usage-query-for-iphone-app/28591707#28591707).

[Stripe Sandbox](https://stripe.com/docs/testing)

[Paypal Sandbox](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts)

**EDIT:** Authorize.net [Payment Diagram Step 3](https://www.authorize.net/resources/howitworksdiagram/) so yes it support multiple gateways because it sends the payment the issuer bank(which is the identified via IIN(Issuer Identification Number)).

```
The Merchant Bank's Processor submits the transaction to the credit card network (like Visa or MasterCard). The credit card network routes the transaction to the bank that issued the credit card to the customer.
```

Comment: erhun, I have used PayLeap as payment gateway as it was used in one of our earlier project  and was looking for PayLeap sanbox for testing and register with them but its not clear as to if they really provide the sandbox for testing free for trial period. Any suggestion/help on this would be of great help.

Comment: You need to send some info to get your test account, please check this link http://www.payleap.com/payleapdev/test-account-2/

Comment: Thanks your input have helped.